# access the jth turtle

Tags: turtle-graphics, iced-coffeescript

In [PencilCode](http://pencilcode.net/), I hatch 10 turtles:

```
turtles = hatch 10
```

How to access only the jth turtle in the "turtles" set (for example only the first turtle)?

I want to apply functions, for example `pen('red').rt(90).fd(100)` to only one of the turtles in the set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The result from hatch is a jquery object, so you can access the jth turtle by using the jquery function eq(j).

For example

```
turtles = hatch 10
turtles.eq(5).pen(red).fd(100)
```